# Malloc/VirtualAlloc prepending FFFFFF after 127 dec

Tags: c++, c, memory, visual-studio-2015, malloc

Whenever I load a struct into memory the memory block seems to contain `ffffff` before certain bytes. After closer inspection I figured this occurs exactly at `0x80` (`128` in dec).

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct __tagMYSTRUCT {
    BYTE unused[4096];
} MYSTRUCT, *PMYSTRUCT;

int main() {
    MYSTRUCT myStruct;

    for (int i = 0; i < 4094; i++) {
        myStruct.unused[i] = 0x00;
    }

    myStruct.unused[4094] = 0x7F; /* No FFFFFF prepend */
    myStruct.unused[4095] = 0x80; /* FFFFFF prepend */ 

    MYSTRUCT *p = (MYSTRUCT*)malloc(4096);
    *p = myStruct;

    char *read = (char*)p;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4096; i++) {
        printf("%02x ", read[i]);
    }

    free(p);
    p = NULL;
    read = NULL;

    return 0;
}
```

Any one knows why this happens and / or how to 'fix' it? (I assume bytes should reach to `0xff`); if I write these bytes to a file, as in, `fwrite(&myStruct, sizeof(myStruct), 1, [filestream])` it doesn't include the `ffffff`'s

Compiler used: `Visual Studio 2015 Community`

P.S. as stated in the title the same occurs when using `VirtualAlloc`

Comment: What's actually wrong? `malloc` makes no assurances about the contents of the memory you receive. It certainly doesn't for instance, clean-up like a land-lord before letting a property to new tenants. If you wish to grab a block of zero-filled memory, you can trivially use `calloc` to allocate and nuke the memory at once, or a traditional `malloc` followed by a `memset` or `ZeroMemory` (if using windows)

Comment: You should replace `*p = myStruct;` by `memcpy(p, &myStruct, sizeof(myStruct);` to copy your array.

Comment: @Franck Did, but doesn't change the contents however, still, `ffffff80`. Thank you, though.

Comment: @enhzflep What's `wrong` is that I would like `80` to be `80` and _not_ `ffffff80`

Comment: `ffffff80` doesn't even fit in a byte

Comment: The (char*)p cast is where this went wrong.  Char is a signed type so byte values >= 0x80 are going to be converted to a negative value when you display them with printf.  Use BYTE or unsigned char.

Comment: @Removed my previous comment was wrong: both syntax `*p = myStruct;` and `memcpy(p, &myStruct, sizeof(myStruct);` are valid in C and copy the inner array. `*p = myStruct;` even enables more compiler optimisations.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's based entirely on a personal misconception about what is going on and is therefore unlikely to be useful to anyone else.

Comment: @HansPassant Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has nothing to do with `VirtualAlloc` nor with `malloc`.

Note that the following details depend on your platform and different things might happen on different operating systems or compilers:

`char` is a signed type (on your platform). It has a range of -128 to 127. When you treat the number 128 as a `char` it wraps around and is actually stored as -128.

`%02x` tells `printf` to print an `unsigned int`, in hexadecimal, with at least two digits. But you are actually passing a `char`. The compiler will automatically convert it to an `int` (with the value -128), which `printf` will then misinterpret as an `unsigned int`. On your platform, `-128` converted to an unsigned int will give the same value as `0xffffff80`.

Comment: Accepted as answer; see @HansPassant 's comment for how-to-fix.